# Assigning format specifier using pointer inside printf() function

Tags: c

I could not understand how the below program code outputs that value.Please help me to understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>
char*s="char*s=%c%s%c;main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}";
int main()
{
        printf(s,34,s,34);
        return 0;
}
```

output:

```
char*s="char*s=%c%s%c;main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}";main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}
```

Comment: Do you understand how printf works?

Comment: Hint: this is not a macro function.

Comment: Sorry this is not a macro function. I was going through bunch of these questions and have given the heading wrongly.

Comment: Thanks for making me to understand about how the output got arrrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printf` statement is effectively equivalent to:

```
printf("char*s=%c%s%c;main(){printf(s,34,s,34);}", 34, s, 34);
               ^ ^ ^
```

I've marked the conversion specifiers with `^`.  These get replaced with, respectively:

- `"` - the ASCII character corresponding to 34
- the contents of `*s`
- `"` - the ASCII character corresponding to 34

Answer (score 2):

It isn't actually a macro in use here.  It is just a simple call to printf.  The first parameter to printf is the format string.  In this case it is the value defined in the global variable `s`.  The format characters `%c%s%c` are supplied by parameters `34,s,34`".  So the string is just printed in its entirety because of the `%s` format character.  And the two 34 values are printed as double quote characters (via `%c`).

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting as an argument your format string, so the output is correct. The %s is replaced with the actual format.
PS: Where are macros?

Comment: Correct, I forgot to write it.